# How do I seperate field and path gps coordinates in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am working on datasets that provides me the GPS Coordinates (Latitudes and Longitudes) of the path covered by a tractor (in .csv format). I want to separate the field and path from the data (refer to the images below).

Sample Dataset: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rVNbkuJuPmcGUzQI9NhKwYJPgcEeypq3

[Plot of my Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFpgW.png)

[Plot Explained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myugr.png)

Here is the code for reading the csv and plotting it,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = r"data_stackoverflow.csv" #importing Data
df = pd.read_csv(path) #Read .csv to a pandas dataframe
latitude = df.Latitude.tolist()    #convert the column Latitude to list, latitude
longitude = df.Longitude.tolist()  #convert the column Longitude to list, longitude

coordinates=list(zip(latitude, longitude))

arr = np.array(coordinates) #numpy array of all points
x=arr[:,[0]]
y=arr[:,[1]]

plt.title("GPS Data Visualized")
plt.xlabel("Latitude")
plt.ylabel("Longitude")

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

**My Question**

How do I separate the path from the field? Is there any specific algorithm to do so?

I have tried implementing DBSCAN on the dataset but the result is not always accurate.

**What should my result be**

I want a dataframe as a result that must gives me field data points only.

The plot of my result should look somewhat like this (field only),

[Sample Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGhbW.png)

Comment: is it always going to be a single field or there might be multiple fields in the same dataset?

Comment: It's always going to be a single field in one dataset.

Comment: well, then you can use another clustering algorithms like `K-means` and specify that you have a single cluster. But i think that you can use [`Outlier Detection` algorithms in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57052795/5741205) - what do you think about provided solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we can consider points belonging to the path to a field as [outliers](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html).

Demo:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

out = IsolationForest(n_estimators=200, contamination="auto", behaviour="new")

df["x"] = out.fit_predict(df[["Latitude", "Longitude"]])

mask = df["x"] == 1

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(10, 10))

ax1.plot(df["Longitude"], df["Latitude"], linewidth=1)
ax2.plot(df.loc[mask, "Longitude"], df.loc[mask, "Latitude"], linewidth=1)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the solution on a few datasets and it seems to work very well.